# Carregamento de arquivo JSON grande

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Pessoal tenho um equipamento aqui que fornece um log em **JSON** que é insere os dados a cada **2 segundos**,Ele fornece esse log para leitura, o problema é que esse arquivo tem log de 30 dias, estou usando ajax para pegar os dados mas demora muito (~ em torno de **3.6 minutos**) para ler o arquivo inteiro, Será que há alguma forma de fazer isso de mais rápido, pois só quero pegar a o ultimo valor que for sendo inseridos no log. Estou tendo fazer assim:

```js
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log(this);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://10.0.0.1/log.json", true);
  xhttp.send();
  }
```

Comment: Devias separar esse log em ficheiros diferentes e o servidor devia enviar pedaços mais pequenos. Qual é o código no servidor que te dá isso?

Comment: Não da pra separar, um um Bunker, ele so fornece esses dados desse modo. é uma aplicaçao embarcada, nao tenho acesso ao codigo.

Comment: Os 3.6 minutos são até o console.log ou até aparecer na página?

Comment: 3.6 é ate o console.log exibir estes dados para que eu possa manipular e exibir na pagina.a pagina carrega normal, 1ms e fica aguardando os dados da requisicao.

Comment: Esses dados são a temperatura do Bunker, entao pra mim só tem utilidade as ultimas informaçoes do json.Mas ter que ler o arquivo todo pra pegar so a ultima informacao, fica inviavel.

Comment: Tens servidor ou a página está com html estático?

Comment: Tenho servidor.

Comment: Podias fazer assim: Faz o servidor ir buscar esse ficheiro de x em x minutos, processá-lo e guardar só o que precisas noutro ficheiro ou memória. Assim o teu JavaScript vai buscar o que precisa ao teu servidor que tem em cache o que precisas, já reduzido. Vale a pena experimentar.

Comment: Vou tentar isso aqui, porém acho que não vai servir o problema é o bunker que só envia dados a 25 kbps, porque como é uma rede local 4 megas ele baixaria super rápido.Mas valeu.